# How to show large amount of data in a table, using react + redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mui-datatable

Im using redux to save a large json data in my global state.
My data is around 100k lines, where each line is just about ~5 attributes.

I was trying to use MUIDataTable in the following way:

```
    const myData = useSelector((state) => state.data.myData)




    <MUIDataTable
         columns={my_columns}
         data={myData}
         options={tableOptions}
     />
```

Its working, but my app is really slow when im using this table. I checked it, and when i remove the table from the app, everything runs really smoothly. When i re-add the table code, everything is slow again.

I read this table library supports paging, and still, its really slow.
Is the issue with the table library im using? is there a better library that handles really large data sets better?
Is the issue with the way im using the global data in redux? do i need to implement some sort of paging myself?

Comment: The issue is not with the table but the size of the data your app is consuming, How are you getting your data?

Comment: If its an api call, then you should pass in query parameter to reduce lifting all of the data at once.

Comment: do i need to implement some sort of paging myself? yes of course, by using `pagination` and `rowsPerPage` props for example...

Comment: im getting my data using a flask webservice, but if i remove the table part, everything works fine. so i assume it does related to the table. just having a large amount of data in my redux global state doesnt cause this issues.

and im using pagination prop in the mui table, just showing 10 rows per page, still really slow.